# ¿Por qué me marca este error? No entiendo porqué ocurre

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo este trabajo para la escuela en c#. Es un programa para calcular áreas de figuras (círculo, cuadrado, triángulo y trapecio). No sé porqué me marca error en esta parte:

```
altura = double.Parse(txtAltura.Text);
```

Cuando estoy depurando el programa, al ingresar datos en los textbox, me marca un error que dice `''No se controló FormatException''`, y abajo de eso `''La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto''`.
No entiendo porqué esto ocurre, no estoy muy avanzado en todo esto.
Este es el código. Agradeceré mucho su ayuda.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AreasCalculator
{
    public partial class AreaCalculator : Form
    {
        double diametro, r, area, bse, altura, lado, altrap, basemayor, basemenor;
        public AreaCalculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnCirculo.Checked == true)
            
                diametro = double.Parse(txtDiametro.Text);
                r = diametro / 2;
                area = 3.1416 * (r * r);
                txtArea.Text = area.ToString();
            
            if (btnTriangulo.Checked == true)

                bse = double.Parse(txtBase.Text);
                altura = double.Parse(txtAltura.Text);
                area = ((bse * altura) / 2);
                txtArea.Text = area.ToString();

            if (btnCuadrado.Checked == true)

                lado = double.Parse(txtLado.Text);
                area = (lado * lado);
                txtArea.Text = area.ToString();

            if (btnTrapecio.Checked == true)

                altrap = double.Parse(txtAlturaTrapecio.Text);
                basemayor = double.Parse(txtBaseMayor.Text);
                basemenor = double.Parse(txtBaseMenor.Text);
                area = (((basemayor + basemenor) * altrap) / 2);
                txtArea.Text = area.ToString();
        }

        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnCirculo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtBase.Visible = false;
            txtAltura.Visible = false;
            lblBase.Visible = false;
            lblAltura.Visible = false;
            txtDiametro.Visible = true;
            lblDiametro.Visible = true;
            txtLado.Visible = false;
            lblLado.Visible = false;
            lblAlturaTrapecio.Visible = false;
            lblBaseMayor.Visible = false;
            lblBaseMenor.Visible = false;
            txtAlturaTrapecio.Visible = false;
            txtBaseMayor.Visible = false;
            txtBaseMenor.Visible = false;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
        }

        private void txtDiametro_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void btnCuadrado_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtBase.Visible = false;
            txtAltura.Visible = false;
            lblBase.Visible = false;
            lblAltura.Visible = false;
            txtDiametro.Visible = false;
            lblDiametro.Visible = false;
            txtLado.Visible = true;
            lblLado.Visible = true;
            lblAlturaTrapecio.Visible = false;
            lblBaseMayor.Visible = false;
            lblBaseMenor.Visible = false;
            txtAlturaTrapecio.Visible = false;
            txtBaseMayor.Visible = false;
            txtBaseMenor.Visible = false;
        }

        private void btnTriangulo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtBase.Visible = true;
            txtAltura.Visible = true;
            lblBase.Visible = true;
            lblAltura.Visible = true;
            txtDiametro.Visible = false;
            lblDiametro.Visible = false;
            txtLado.Visible = false;
            lblLado.Visible = false;
            lblAlturaTrapecio.Visible = false;
            lblBaseMayor.Visible = false;
            lblBaseMenor.Visible = false;
            txtAlturaTrapecio.Visible = false;
            txtBaseMayor.Visible = false;
            txtBaseMenor.Visible = false;

        }

        private void btnTrapecio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblAlturaTrapecio.Visible = true;
            lblBaseMayor.Visible = true;
            lblBaseMenor.Visible = true;
            txtAlturaTrapecio.Visible = true;
            txtBaseMayor.Visible = true;
            txtBaseMenor.Visible = true;
            txtBase.Visible = false;
            txtAltura.Visible = false;
            lblBase.Visible = false;
            lblAltura.Visible = false;
            txtDiametro.Visible = false;
            lblDiametro.Visible = false;
            txtLado.Visible = false;
            lblLado.Visible = false;
        }

        private void txtCuadrado_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los datos que ingresas?

Comment: Si es círculo, diámetro. Si es cuadrado, lado. Si es triángulo, base y altura. Si es trapecio, base mayor, base menor y altura.

Comment: Creo que no me dejé entender, aquí tienes una recomendaciones generales, te serán de ayuda: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos. PD: Punto 4 en especial.

Comment: El valor que se esta ingresando en el textbox cual es ??? Ejemplo : 20 , 30 , 40 cuanto se esta ingresando cuando falla?

Comment: Falla al ingresar cualquier cantidad